# multiple-cursors activates M-x automatically

Tags: multiple-cursors, m-x

Somehow when running `mc/edit-beginnings-of-lines` and  `mc/edit-ends-of-lines` it activates `M-x` for all lines, not letting me use the cursors, how to solve this? I just took a look at `.mc-lists.el` and there's nothing suspicious there.

Comment: Does this happen if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file), and then load just multiple-cursors? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Tried the -Q option and loaded the package, all seemed to work fine, then after inspecting my init.el I didn't noticed any problem. What I do have noticed is that any mc/command executed with M-x over 2+ lines gives this error:
Error in post-command-hook (mc/execute-this-command-for-all-cursors): (quit)
which I'm failing to understand why

Comment: Please put all relevant info in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx. You might also want to contact the maintainer of the multiple-cursors code, if you don't get a helpful answer here.